# How to get elements having the same keyword in href

Tags: javascript

I understand in order to get a `<link>` element with a specific *href* you can use:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("link[href='https://example.com']");
```

Suppose I have several links with different *href* values such as:

> https://example.com/link-1
>
> https://example.com/link-2
>
> //example.com/link-3
>
> //example.com/link-4

Is there any way to get all the `<link>` tags having the keyword **example.com** in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="example.com"]');
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<a href="https:example.com">test</a>
<a href="https:example.com">test</a>
<a href="https:example.com">test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='https://example.com']")

is the css selector that gives all the href that contains example.com. This checks for substring of https://example.com in every link and picks all of them.